# Change shortcut in Firefox for "next tab" to F3?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> will switch to the next or previous tab in Firefox.

However I would much prefer to use <kbd>F2</kbd> / <kbd>F3</kbd> for the same purpose, similar to the old Maxthon behaviour. Is this possible?

Comment: ctrl+tab and ctrl+shift+tab do the same thing in Firefox and many other tabbed applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SwiftTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59011/) addon should do what you're looking for.